# Formulario no me actualiza datos cuando actualizo

Tags: php, crud

Buenos dias
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual me piden hacer un formulario ABM y yo lo hice de la siguiente forma

esto seria el archivo editar.php donde esta el boton actualizar que lleva a otra pagina para editar los datos y luego los actualiza en el index

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hoja.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>ACTUALIZAR</h1>

<?php
 
include("conexion.php");
 
if(!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"])){

$Id=$_GET["IdCliente"];
 
$Nombre=$_GET["Nombre"];
 
$Apellido=$_GET["Apellido"];
 
$Direccion=$_GET["Direccion"];

}else{
$Id=$_POST["IdCliente"];
 
$Nombre=$_POST["Nombre"];
 
$Apellido=$_POST["Apellido"];
 
$Direccion=$_POST["Direccion"];
 
$consulta="UPDATE cliente SET Nombre=:clinom, Apellido=:cliape, Direccion=:clidir WHERE IdCliente=:cliid";
 
$resultado=$conexion->prepare($consulta);
 
$resultado->execute(array(":cliid"=>$Id, ":clinom"=>$Nombre, ":cliape"=>$Apellido, ":clidir"=>$Direccion));
 
header("location:index.php");
 



}
 
?>

<p>
 
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <table width="25%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><label for="IdCliente"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="IdCliente" id="IdCliente"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td><label for="Nombre"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" value="<?php echo $Nombre?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td><label for="Apellido"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Apellido" id="Apellido" value="<?php echo $Apellido?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dirección</td>
      <td><label for="Direccion"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Direccion" id="Direccion" value="<?php echo $Direccion?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="bot_actualizar" id="bot_actualizar" value="Actualizar"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Este segundo codigo pertenece a index.php(es solo un fragmento)

```html
<?php
   foreach($registros as $clientes): ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->IdCliente?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Nombre?></td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Apellido?></td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Direccion?></td>
 
      <td class="bot"><a href="borrar.php?Direc=<?php echo $clientes->Direccion?>"><input type='button' name='del' id='del' value='Borrar'></a></td>
      <td class='bot'><a href="editar.php?IdCliente=<?php echo $clientes->IdCliente?> & Nombre=<?php echo $clientes->Nombre?> & Apellido=<?php echo $clientes->Apellido?> & Direccion=<?php echo $clientes->Direccion?>"><input type='button' name='up' id='up' value='Actualizar'></a></td>
    </tr>    
    
    <?php
```

y por ultimo (por las dudas) el tercero que es el de la conexion.php

```html
<?php


try{
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=cliente_factura', 'root', '');
 
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 
$conexion->exec("Set character set utf8"); 
 
 
}catch (Exception $e){
 
die('Error' . $conexion->getMessage());
echo "Linea de error" . $conexion->getLine(); 
 
 
}



?>
```

Y haciendo todo esto sigue sin actualziarme los datos que cambio en la otra pagina y que leugo , supuestamente , deberian volver al index.php

No se cual es el error

Comment: Verifica siempre lo siguiente: 1. Que la conexión sea válida `if ($conexion) { ... }`; 2. Que la consulta se preparó sin error: `$resultado=$conexion->prepare($consulta);` Luego: `if ($resultado) { ... } ` por cada bloque pon `else`  con mensajes que indiquen lo que ha ocurrido. Recuerda que los nombres de tablas y columnas pueden ser *case sensitive*, o sea que debes escribirlos en tu consulta tal como se llaman en la base de datos, usando las mayúsculas y minúsculas de forma idéntica. Sería bueno que pongas una etiqueta con el manejador de base de datos que estás usando.

Comment: Si supiera que es eso del manejador de base de datos aportaria la mayor cantidad de informacion posible